# NetBeansでダウンロード済プラグインを追加しようとすると強制終了してしまう

Tags: netbeans

IDEによるRuby on Railsの開発環境を構築しようとしております。

NetBeansをインストールし起動したのち、「ツール」→「プラグイン」→「ダウンロード済」と進み、「プラグインの追加」をクリックした途端、NetBeansが強制終了してしまいます。

その際特にメッセージ等も表示されません。

色々ネット検索で原因を探ってみたのですが全く解決に至りませんでした。

原因の調べ方や強制終了されない方法等、問題解決の方法をご存知でしたらご教示いただけないでしょうか。

情報もろもろ不足しているかとは思いますが、お力を貸していただければ幸いです。

あるいは他に良いRoRの開発環境があれば教えてください。

＜環境＞
NetBeans（8.2）
Windows10
Java（1.8.0_171）

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/132720

Comment: 有料ですが、RubyMineが好きです。JetBrainsのAll Products Pack(個人 年間:28000円ぐらい)を買っておけば, 必要な言語に応じたIDEとか利用できます。IDEはどれも同様のインターフェイスなので、セットアップで嵌る時間や学習時間を省けるので気にいってます。